# libc.6 is a symlink to libc-2-31?

Tags: symbolic-link, c

I'm running ubuntu 20.04, and I'm tryying to run a python pwn script that has the following line:

```
libc = ELF("./libc.so.6")
```

Which fails with:

```
No such file or directory: './libc.so.6'
```

So I check my libc version (for the file i'm trying to target):

```
$ ldd r2c
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdd95e1000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2505727000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2505938000)
```

and I try to update the python script accordingly

```
libc = ELF("./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 ")
```

But this fails in the same manner.
I then check this file:

```
$ file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: symbolic link to libc-2.31.so
```

Which apparently is just a symlink to some other libc version? how does that make sense?

Can I do something to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you're telling your program to look in the current directory by specifying `./`. Remove the `.`, and you'll start the search at `/`, the root directory of the whole file system

Comment: This has the same effect